# Camelot Table Extraction Error (PdfReadWarning: incorrect startxref pointer(0) [_reader.py:938])

Tags: python, pdf, tabula, python-camelot

I am trying to extract some tables from a .pdf doc but I got an error:

> "PdfReadWarning: incorrect startxref pointer(0) [_reader.py:938]"

The code is pretty simple because I am just testing:

```
import camelot

file = r"myPCPath\myFile.pdf"

tables = camelot.read_pdf(file)
print(tables)
```

All the dependencies was installed and I didnt found any information about this issue :(

Comment: It could be related to the "quality" of the pdf